# Filtered uitableview doesn't call didSelectRowAtIndexPath when clicked on one of the results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a searchbar on my tableview. Everything works except when the results are displayed. I want to click on the result and do a segue.

Now I click on it and the didSelectRowAtIndexpath isn't called.

This is my uibar and searchcontroller:

```
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
_searchBar.delegate = self;

searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchBar;
```

Implemented this delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But this is not called when I click on one of the results.

Do I need to add another delegate?

Comment: Where is your tableView delegate ....

Comment: You dont need another delegate. Are you using customCell if yes, try with a simple UITableViewCell

Comment: I'm using standard cells. And this is my     _poiTableView = [[POITableViewController alloc] init];
    _poiTableView.delegate = self; delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the delegate of search results table view, with searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

```
searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
```